# Logstash not writing output to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

The code mentioned is my logstash conf file  . I provide my nginx access log file as input and output to elasticsearch .I also write the output to a text file which works fine .. But the output is never been written to elasticsearch.

```
input {
  file {
    path => "filepath"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
} 
output {
  file {
    path => "filepath"
  }
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
    port => "9200"
  }
}
```

I also tried executing logstash binary from command line using -e option

```
 input { stdin{ } output { elasticsearch { host => localhost } }
```

which works fine. I get the output written to elasticsearch.. But in the former case i dont . Help me solve this

Comment: what versions are you using? I guess you could add the protocol http, maybe that helps.

Comment: If that was the case i should not have got the output while using stdin { }

Comment: Can you try it as     port => 9200 , without double quotes.

Comment: already tried that too ..

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few things, I have no idea why your case with just host works. If I try it, i get timeouts. This is the configuration that works for me:

```
elasticsearch {
    protocol => "http"
    host => "localhost"
    port => "9200"
}
```

I tried with logstash 1.4.2 and elasticsearch 1.4.4

Comment: There was problem with logsttash . . I tried re-installing logstash and everything works fine now